# User Profile Service Application is not showing in Server Applications page

Tags: user-profile-service

I installed SharePoint 2010 Foundation (Standalone) on my development machine but for some reason, "User Profile Service Application" is not showing 
in Service Applications (http://:24955/_admin/ServiceApplications.aspx). If I click on "New" button in Server Applications, it only shows "Business Data Connectivity Service" menu item.

I am wondering if I also require to install SharePoint Service 2010 to have User Profile Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Profile Service in not part of SharePoint Foundation only SharePoint Server

Answer (score 0):

In Standalone mode the User Profile Service Application is NOT provisioned, therefore behavior is appropriate. You do need to re-install SharePoint Server in Farm mode.